# how to send HTTP Authentication to SSL enable server with jquery ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, http-authentication

I have a REST based server which I am trying to communicate with using JQuery. Both XML and JSON are available as response formats, so I am using JSON.

The connections are all SSL so HTTP Authentication has been our authorization method of choice, and we have had no problems with other frontends (raw Javascript, Silverlight, etc...)

Now I am attempting to put something together with jQuery and having endless problems using HTTP Basic Authentication.

I have scoured through numerous previous questions most of which either have solutions that do not seem to actually work or blame the entire problem on cross origin access, which I have already overcome in Javascript testing. The responses always provide Access-Control-Allow-Origin set to the provided Origin header in the request, and this can be seen in the responses of my tests.

In basic jQuery, this entire call is very simply accomplished with:

```
req.open('GET', 'https://servertest:8222/Vcard', true, 'testing', 'testingpassword');
```

**The JQuery ajax call:**

```
$.ajax({
        username: 'testing',
        password: 'testingpassword',
        url: 'https://servertest:8222/Vcard',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        /*data: { username: 'testing', password: 'testingpassword' },*/
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",
                // encodeBase64(username + ":" + password));
                "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=");
        },
        sucess: function(result) {
            out('done');
        }
    });
```

The only method that actually seems to work to provide authentication is the direct insertion of the **Base64 encoded** data in the `beforeSend()` function. If this is not included, there is no progress made whatsoever. Username and password properties seem to be ignored entirely.

With the beforeSend()`enter code here` behavior provided, the GET call gets a positive response with data included. However, because this is a cross site call, an OPTIONS call is performed ahead of the GET call and always fails, because it does not make use of `beforeSend()` and therefore gets a **401 response** due to failed authentication.

Is there a better way to accomplish what should be a very trivial call? Should the fact that the **OPTIONS** request does not make use of the `beforeSend()` function processing be considered a bug? Is there perhaps a way to disable the OPTIONS check entirely? It is not possible to make this call not **cross-site**, as Javascript seems to consider even a different port number on the same machine as **"cross-site"**.

Any help would be appreciated....